# struts2 combobox - pass Integer id and not String name through the form to the action

Tags: forms, combobox, struts2, action

my form is passing the String name of the country to the action. how can i pass the id of the object country from the combobox to the action?

this is what i have:

s:combobox label="Country" name="country" headerValue="Select" headerKey="1" list="%{countries}" listValue="name"/>

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the **listKey** attribute.
If you change it as:

```
<s:combobox label="Country" name="country" headerValue="Select" headerKey="1"
list="%{countries}" listValue="name" listKey="id"/>
```

It will probably work.

See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/combobox.html for all the attributes available.